# How Can I change Workflow at run time?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

This is my requirement.

I have a order workflow, where when ever a order is received it should be shipped by shipper "B". Now I want to change the order to be shipped by shipper "C". how can I change the workflow at run time

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4.5 introduced a number of great new enhancements to handle workflow versioning scenarios like this.  Here's a great article that summarizes the features (note the section on Versioning, in particular):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781025.aspx

Your solution will depend on what host you are currently using (WorkflowApplication or WorkflowServiceHost), how you are persisting those instances, and whether or not you want to modify new instances only vs. existing running instances.

Let me know some of those details and I'll try to help more.

Thanks,

-- Dave, WF Team